# Mule ESB: How to use a flow execution conditional on a JSON object

Tags: json, conditional-statements, mule, esb

Mule ESB

I am trying to convert a Hello World program into a program that will accept a JSON object, examine the data, and route the execution accordingly.

Below is a copy of my flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" version="EE-3.5.0" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <json:object-to-json-transformer name="Object_to_JSON" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <flow doc:name="HelloWorldFlow1" name="HelloWorldFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message." doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" contentType="application/json"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I see the object-to-json in the code, which I believe is configured from the
HTTP Node->HTTP Settings->content type, which is set to

```
application/json
```

So I assume that the incoming object is in JSON format once within the flow, with no fursther Object to JSON nodes required.

I am sending the following string to the flow:

```
{ "uid" : "ABCxxx" }
```

What I am trying to achieve to get a node that will examine and verify that the first three letters of the uid is "ABC", and if so send it down one path, but if the first three characters of the uid does not equal "ABC", to go down another path., sort of like a IF statement with a true and a false configtion,

The following is a Pseudo code example

```
IF uid[3] == "ABC"
   GOTO Database Connector
else
   GOTO JSON-TO-OBJECT Transformer
```

My question is:  Whhich node should I use to perform this, should I use an Expression filter or other

... and how do I write that in JSAONPath (or other)

(Does Mule ESB perform this sort of thing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th json evaluator that executes JsonPath in mule is deprecated in favor of MEL. The preferred approach now is to convert json to an object and query the object instead. One of the simplest approaches is to convert the json to the map and use MEL to query the map. Like so:

```
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />

        <choice>
            <when expression="#[payload.uid == 'ABC']">

            </when>
        </choice>
```

More info here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips

Answer (score 0):

You can also `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" />` alternatively 
and then

```
 <choice>
        <when expression="#[message.payload.uid == 'ABC']">
```